# Dotted line between two sentence but sentence is fixed width

Tags: html, css

I want two sentence with fixed width:30% but my first div "**words**" go to the next line. **class="left" words** is not show properly and another my second next div "**words**" **mixed** with this **first div**

**HTML**

```
<div class="bg">
    <span class="left">Hello Hello Hello Hello my text is missing plz show</span>
    <span class="right">My friend.</span>
</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
<div class="bg">
    <span class="left">sohan sohan sohan sohan sohan sohan sohan</span>
    <span class="right">My friend.</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bg{width:90%; margin:0 auto; position:relative;}
.bg .left{width:auto; max-width:30%; min-width:10%; position:absolute; text-align:justify; background-color:white;}
.bg .right{width:auto; max-width:30%; min-width:10%; float:right; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden; text-align:justify; background-color:white;}
.bg .left:before {
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    content:
 ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
 ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
 ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ."}
.clear{clear:both;}
```

**RESULT**

```
Hello Hello Hello Hello.................................... My friend.
sohan sohan sohan ......................................... My Friend.
sohan sohan sohan sohan
```

Comment: remove `position:absolute` from `.bg .left`

Comment: if i remove position:absolute in .bg.left. My width is not set in 30%;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `position:absolute` from `.bg .left` and instead add `display:inline-block` to reestablish block context which allows a width to be set on your `span`s (which by default are inline elements and thus don't respect width declarations). Also you should change to `float:right` on your `.bg .left:before`.

[Your fixed Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TV4XU/1)